# Converting a Doc object into a string in python

Tags: python, minidom

I'm using minidom to parse through an xml document. I took the data with yum tags and stored them in a list and calculated the frequency of the words. However, its not storing or reading them as strings in the list. Is there another way to do it? Right now this is what I have:

```
yumNodes = [node for node in doc.getElementsByTagName("yum")]

for node in yumNodes:
    yumlist.append(t.data for t in node.childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)

for ob in yumlist:
    for o in ob:
        if word not in freqDict:
            freqDict[word] = 1
        else:
            freqDict[word] += 1
```

Comment: Could you post part of your XML too?

Comment: How about listing the specific exception you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly related to your question, but as a remark that could improve your code...the pattern

```
freqDict = {}
...
if word not in freqDict:
    freqDict[word] = 1
else:
    freqDict[word] += 1
```

is usually replaced with

```
import collections
freqDict = collections.defaultdict(int)
...
freqDict[word] += 1
```

or pre-2.5

```
freqDict = {}
...
freqDict.setdefault(word, 0) += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
yumlist.append(t.data for t in node.childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)
```

with the following:

```
yumlist.append(t.nodeValue for t in node.childNodes if t.nodeType == 3)
```